# how to select specific columns from three different tables in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I am trying to select values from three different tables.
When I select all columns it works well, but if I select specific column, the SQL Error [42000]: JDBC-8027:Column name is ambiguous. appear.

this is the query that selected all that works well

```
SELECT 
*
FROM (SELECT x.*, B.*,C.* , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY x.POLICY_NO) policy_no_count 
FROM YIP.YOUTH_POLICY x
 LEFT JOIN
 YIP.YOUTH_POLICY_AREA B
 ON x.POLICY_NO = B.POLICY_NO
 LEFT JOIN
 YIP.YOUTH_SMALL_CATEGORY C
 ON B.SMALL_CATEGORY_SID = C.SMALL_CATEGORY_SID
ORDER BY x.POLICY_NO);
```

and this is the error query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
x.POLICY_NO,
x.POLICY_TITLE,
policy_no_count ,
B.SMALL_CATEGORY_SID,
C.SMALL_CATEGORY_TITLE 
FROM (SELECT x.*, B.*,C.* , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY x.POLICY_NO) policy_no_count 
        FROM YIP.YOUTH_POLICY x
        LEFT JOIN
         YIP.YOUTH_POLICY_AREA B
        ON x.POLICY_NO = B.POLICY_NO
        LEFT JOIN
         YIP.YOUTH_SMALL_CATEGORY C
        ON B.SMALL_CATEGORY_SID = C.SMALL_CATEGORY_SID
        ORDER BY x.POLICY_NO);
```

I am trying to select if A.POLICY_NO values duplicate rows more than 18, want to change C.SMALL_CATEGORY_TITLE values to "ZZ" and also want to cahge B.SMALL_CATEGORY_SID values to null.
that is why make 2 select in query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
x.POLICY_NO,
CASE WHEN (policy_no_count > 17) THEN 'ZZ' ELSE C.SMALL_CATEGORY_TITLE END AS C.SMALL_CATEGORY_TITLE,
CASE WHEN (policy_no_count > 17) THEN NULL ELSE B.SMALL_CATEGORY_SID END AS B.SMALL_CATEGORY_SID,
x.POLICY_TITLE
FROM (SELECT x.*, B.*,C.* , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY x.POLICY_NO) policy_no_count 
        FROM YIP.YOUTH_POLICY x
        LEFT JOIN
         YIP.YOUTH_POLICY_AREA B
        ON x.POLICY_NO = B.POLICY_NO
        LEFT JOIN
         YIP.YOUTH_SMALL_CATEGORY C
        ON B.SMALL_CATEGORY_SID = C.SMALL_CATEGORY_SID
        ORDER BY x.POLICY_NO);
```

If i use that query, I got SQL Error [42000]: JDBC-8006:Missing FROM keyword.   ¶at line 3, column 80 of null error..

I know I should solve it step by step. Is there any way to select specific columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's most probably because of `SELECT x.*, B.*,C.*` - avoid asterisks - explicitly name all columns you need, and then pay attention to possible duplicate column names; if you have them, use column **aliases**.

For example, if that `select` (which is in a subquery) evaluates to

```
select x.id, x.name, b.id, b.name
```

then outer query doesn't know which `id` you want as two columns are named `id` (and also two `name`s), so you'd have to

```
select x.id   as x_id,
       x.name as x_name,
       b.id   as b_id,
       b.name as b_name
from ...
```

and - in outer query - select not just `id`, but e.g. `x_id`.

Comment: It works well. thank you i learned it!